# como darle un valor entero a un string netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy trabajando con int, pero quisiera saber si hay modo de que al colocar la palabra "si" "no" en "bisi" (es la tercera entrada) tenga un valor numeral, como, si=1 o no=0, como se ve la imagen puse unas indicaciones de colocar 1 si es bisiesto y 0 si no lo es, no si me deje entender, gracias al que me resuelva la duda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el código como texto, no como imagen. Revisar también [ask],saludos.

Comment: Netbeans es una IDE... supongo que vos queres lograr eso en JAVA, no?

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido, vamos por partes, en java un "int" nace "int" y muere "int", no se puede castear, lo que puedes hacer es declarar "bici" como string, y asignarle un "si" o un "no", algo así: String bici = ""; bici = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Ingrese `si` si es biciesto o `no` si no lo es" );

Comment: Te sugiero que elimines la imagen y coloques el código como texto, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos.